# Not naming a child "Akiva" - minhag?

Tags: minhag, names, rabbi-akiva-ben-yosef

I recently spoke to a person who said that their rabbi advised them against naming their child "Akiva" because of his ill-fated death; it was some sort of negative omen. Regardless, the couple liked the name Akiva and settled on keeping it, but only as a second name.

I have never heard of such a (can we call it) custom. Does anyone know of a source for such a thing?

Comment: I've never heard this about Akiva. But there are instances where I have heard this. We know someone who was rachmana litzlan in a v bad accident and was left paralysed. A couple had a baby and liked two names (one a personal preference, and the second after a relative) that just happened to be the full name of this person. When the Rov heard he told them to switch the names round so the baby would not share the same name.

Comment: Consider Rabbi Akiva Eiger, who was named after his mothers father, Rabbi Akiva Eger. https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/112047/jewish/Rabbi-Akiba-Eger.htm   Se also: http://www.loebtree.com/eger.html

Comment: One rabbi's personal opinion on naming a child doesn't make it a "minhag".

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi hence I said "can we call it" minhag. I don't know what it is or why this rabbi would say it, hence the inquiry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So firstly, by way of introduction, it is important to note the power of a name. The Gemara in [Brachos 7b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.7b.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) famously notes that a name can affect the child's future.

Interestingly, HaRav Moshe Sternbach shlita in [Teshuvos Vehanhagos, Vol 2, YD #501](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20026&st=&pgnum=415&hilite=) when asked about whether one can name after a relative who was irreligious, makes a point of mentioning the following:

> ונראה שהנולד **קשור למזל** ומדות של הנפטר ולא קשור למעשיו
>
> And it appears that the child **is connected to the mazal (luck/destiny)** and the character attributes of the departed but not connected to his actions

As such, if the dead relative had a life marred by bad occurrences, who had a bad "mazal" - naming the child with the same name forms a similar type mazal. Which in this context, would be advisable to avoid.

When digging further I came across the [Sefer Chasidim 244](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_Chasidim.244.1?lang=bi) which says outright that a person should not name after a relative that suffered etc.:

> ועוד אומר דברי' שהש' גורם לטובה או לרעה לטובה יש אדם שכל הנקראין בשמו יצליחו לגדולה זהו ויקרא בהם שמי ושם אבותי. וכתיב (ישעיהו סו כב) כי כאשר השמי' החדשי' והארץ החדשה אשר אני עושה עומדי' לפני אמר ה' כן יעמוד זרעכם ושמכם. וכתיב (ישעיהו מג א) קראתי בשמך לי אתה. הרי שיש אדם שכל אותם הנקראים על שמו יחיו ויהיו בניו קיימי' ויעמידו תולדות ויש שכל אלה להם להפך שנאמר (ישעיהו סה טו) והנחת' שמכם לשבועה לבחירי והמיתך ה' ולעבדיו יקרא שם אחר וכתיב (ישעיהו יד כב) והכרתי לבבל שם ושאר ונין ונכד וכתיב (איוב יח יט) לא נין ולא נכד בעמו ואין שריד במגוריו. וכתיב (איוב יח יז) ולא שם לו על פני חוץ. לכן יתפלל אדם שכל הנקראי' בשמו יהיו בהם מדות טובות האלה ולא אחת מן המדות הרעות ושלא יקראו זרעו על אותן שמדות הרעות תלויות בהן. כיצד יראה אדם כשיש שני אחי' וקראו שם בניהם ובנותיהם אחר שם פלוני אפילו אחר צדיק ומתו בלא תולדות. **או שהיו הכתובים למעלה לרעה בהם אל יקראו יותר באותו השם ר"ל** שקראו לו שם בגורל מתוך הספר כאשר עושין לחולה או בשני אחי' נתקיי' למאן דאמ' שני' לחזקה ולמאן דאמר שלשה לחזק' פעמים שהאחי' קוראי' בשם אותו האיש ונכשלים זרעו או האחים קראו את בניהם אחר אביהם ומתו והבנו' קראו בניהן וחיו ויש שם פלוני שכל המשפחה שלו אם קראו זרעם בשמם מתו בלא תולדות ולא האריכו ימיהם ובכל ענינים האלו לנקבות ובשם שירא' החכם שכך הוא אל יאמר אקיי' לאבותי שם שלא ישכח והוא רואה שנקראים אחרים ונכשלו הרי הוא נושא אל נפשו עון. ואין אלו הדברים משום ניחוש שהרי הראשונים היו קוראים את בניהם על שם המאורע ולא מתו. אא"כ חטאו בער ואונן לכך יהיו צדיקים שזרעם מתים ולא מחמת עון. אלא שאלו הדברים הזיקו ואע"פ כן יש לאדם לחשוב שמא בעונו הוא וכל שמתים בניו ואחרים קראו אחר פלוני וזה קראו כמו כן ומתו הרי נגזר עליו לפי שכינו אחרים שם כמוהו

---

**UPDATE**

I came across this link [here](https://www.bvkkosher.com/naming---halacha-and-hashkafa) (see Part II) which has several sources. He also addresses your question about Akiva.

It writes in [Seder HaDoros](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46819&st=&pgnum=311&hilite=) that the author of the [Ohr Zaruah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_ben_Moses_of_Vienna) had a dream where he questioned how Akiva should be spelt - with the final letter being an aleph or a hei. In the dream he saw the verse from [Tehillim 97:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.97.11?lang=bi)

> א֭וֹר זָרֻ֣**עַ** לַצַּדִּ֑י**ק** וּֽלְיִשְׁרֵ**י**־לֵ֥**ב** שִׂמְחָֽ**ה**
>
> Light is sown for the righteous, radiance for the upright.

He realised that the end letters (higlighted in bold) spelt Akiva with the last letter being a hei.

In the [Shu"t Chasam Sofer, Even HaEzer 2:28](https://www.sefaria.org/Responsa_Chatam_Sofer%2C_Even_HaEzer.2.28.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) he questions how it is spelt in the Gemara (with an aleph) and how there is now a shift to using a hei. The Chasam Sofer explains there that it is due to "דריע מזליה" - "bad mazal". Therefore, even though Rebbe Akiva was a tzaddik willing to die "al kiddush Hashem", due to his tragic end we would need to make a change in the name before applying it to our children.

Rav Moshe Feinstein zt"l in [Igros Moshe, YD 2:122](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14676&st=&pgnum=192&hilite=) discusses whether one should name a child after a person who died young, and his response is that it should be "קצת קפידא", done with some reservation. He brings down the [Yam Shel Shlomo on Gittin 4:31](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40935&st=&pgnum=57) who felt that one should strongly avoid such names, and notes that even the name Yeshayahu (Isaiah) has been changed to Yeshayah due to his tragic end (see [Yevamos 49b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.49b.7-9?lang=bi)).

(see there for further details).

Comment: It would be worth quoting the end of Rav Moshe Feinstein's Tshuva where he addresses Akiva specifically with the spelling differences.

Comment: Thanks @user6591 - but he quotes the Chasam Sofer which I already mentioned.